# Finding the CDF of $Z=X+Y$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

> Given $Z=X+Y$, find the CDF of $Z$

The region on the plane is $Z=X+Y≤z$ so the CDF is $$F_{Z}(z)=
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{z-x}_{-\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{dydx}
$$
My question is, **why is the integration limits of $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ instead of $x\in(-\infty,z-y)$?**

I suspect that this is because of the type of integral? Or in fact, we can first integrate with respect to $x$ with the said bound and the bound for $y$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$ however the integration region is a triangle and I don't think that either of the two bounds should have a $\infty$

Comment: You let the $x$ go freely, and just restrict $y$ such that $x+y\le z$. Or you can let $y$ go freely and restrict $x$ such that $x+y\le z$, in which case you get F_{Z}(z)=
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{z-y}_{-\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\text{dxdy}. It's all about the order you choose when you calculate the iterated integral.

Comment: @Momo I've seen it in my calculus book however it is not intuitive for me. The integration region is a "finite" triangle so I don't think that $y$ could approach $\infty$

Comment: Oh, so it means that a single restriction on $y$ for example would already impose a condition for $x$ such that $y+x≤z$? Is that why we can choose $x$ to have such freedom?

Comment: If $f$ has bounded support, then you can place further restrictions on $x$ and $y$

Comment: That garbled text in my comment is supposed to say $F_{Z}(z)= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{z-y}_{-\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dxdy$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: A graph of the region x + y <= z]

The above graph shows the region $x + y \leq z$. To integrate over the region, you need to integrate over every valid $(x, y)$ pair. Notice that the region includes valid points for every possible $x$, i.e. $-\infty < x < \infty$, but once you pick a value of $x$ the only valid range for $y$ is $-\infty < y < z - x$. So one option for the double integral is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f(x, y) dy\ dx$ - note that the $dx$ pairs with the first integral sign, and so it goes last so that together they envelop the integral over $y$. This is because outside of the integral signs $x$ and $y$ don't exist - $x$ is defined only within the first integral, and $y$ only within the second.

Alternatively, you could swap $x$ and $y$ and make the same kind of argument - all values of $y$ are possible, but for any given value of $y$ the range of $x$ is restricted to a maximum of $z - y$, so you would calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f(x, y) dx\ dy$.

*Alternatively*, you could transform the variables $x$ and $y$. For example, if you set $u = x - y$ and $v = x + y$, then the region becomes $v \leq z$, with no restriction on $u$ at all, but then you need to do some magic on the integral to accommodate the substitution, and I suspect that's not something you're dealing with at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why is the integration limits of $x∈(−∞,∞)$ instead of $x∈(−∞,z−y)$?

$y$ is the variable of integration for the definite integral: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y$, which is the interior integral.  That variable exists only within the scope of the integral; it does not exist outside its evaluation. It cannot be used to bound the exterior integral.

So the exterior integral must covers *all* values of $x$, while the interior covers the values of $y$ that satisfy the constraint $x+y\leq z$.  In short:

$${\{\langle x,y\rangle\in(-\infty,\infty)^2: x+y\leq z\}}~=~{\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\in(-\infty,\infty), y\in(-\infty , z-x]\}}$$

> however the integration region is a triangle and I don't think that either of the two bounds should have a $∞$

The integration region is the *semi-plane* at and below the line $y = z-x$.

Well, unless the support for the function places further restrictions (because the function is zero values outside the support, by definition).  However, that is another issue.